# What effects would banning opposite-sex mating have on sexuality?

Tags: humans, sex

A load of children/teens developed magic mutations, so the government kidnapped them and locked them away for life. Due to the magic the kids can't be sterilized, and for economic and scientific reasons they can only do a single mixed-sex facility. The kids have little-to-no contact with the outside world, and any they do have is tightly controlled

To help curb reproduction, the facility forbids the kids from mating with the opposite sex. My question is to ask what effects this would have on the kids' sexuality as a whole. Specifically, how would the overall rates of different sexualities change due to this prohibition?

Comment: Well, if the ban was supported by effective enforcement measures there's one obvious effect it would have on the sexuality of a subject species .. it would end all forms of sexuality in the subject species, because it would become extinct 

Comment: What makes you think that something as complex as human culture or sexuality would have a sufficiently predictable response to make this question have sufficiently specific answers to make this as anything other than an exercise in the sort of brainstorming not permitted on this site?

Comment: It's perhaps not going to have much effect on the sexuality of the individuals in your example though, there is allegedly a degree of additional same sex relationships that supposedly occurs in same sex facilities such as jails but it might be argued that those individuals that do go that way we're bi to some degree anyway so that the alleged statistics (if real and not just an old wives tale) would be providing a false positive in respect of what you're looking for, i.e. their sexuality didn't change, only the available variety of partners to choose from.

Comment: Just do what's already being done --- chemical and physiological sterilisation. I.e., crack the nuts. Sexuality itself then becomes a non-issue. As a side effect, you get no babies.

Comment: @elemtilas apparently that magic helps them to regenerate lost parts, so neither would help for long, or maybe even for short.

Comment: How is this different from any real-world boarding school?

Comment: Strictly speaking, banning mating with the opposite sex is not the same thing as banning heterosexuality. You can be bisexual, pansexual etc and still be attracted to the opposite sex. Heck, [you don't even need to be attracted to the opposite sex in the first place to have kids with them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beard_(companion)).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails "the book test": If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: It's also possible for heterosexual partners to participate in sexual activity that would not possibly result in pregnancy and while not a 100% perfect solution, would work as a viable birth control.  One problem with this question is that the reduction of human reproduction in a population is a genocidal act and if that's the desired outcome of the government, this is a complicated and financially draining method to achieve the same results that can be done faster and cheaper with bullets.

Comment: @hszmv it doesn't have to be a genocidal intent though, any system might need occasional balancing, including a nation's population to remain within numbers their available resources can be expected to support (such as the land available to them for agriculture if importing food is not an option for some reason), short term adjustments for such purposes rather than the unending permanent application of such measures as we were thinking of might be all the OP has in mind here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## False rape accusations would become more common and pregnancies would be routine.

As with normal schools which ban reproduction, teenagers being horny would have sex a lot. Because they were not prepared for it, they wouldn't use contraceptives.

When women got pregnant and were unable to get an abortion quickly enough, they would likely blame disliked minorities or scorned lovers as forcing them, to avoid being accused of having consensual heterosexual sex.

Answer (score 7):

It wouldn't.

You can forbid it all you want, it's still going to happen.

You can no more force a horny teen not to be straight than an evangelical christian can force a gay man to be straight.

Answer (score 1):

**The premise just isn't feasible.**

If the teens have enough freedom to have any sexual activity then there isn't any way this makes sense. Even if it did, sexuality is an insanely complex spectrum with multiple dimensions too. Honestly, they should just keep them locked down enough that there is no sexual activity what so ever. It's easier to keep a 24/7 watch on them and prohibit physical contact than anything else. Also, abortion is not sterilization, so if a girl were to get pregnant, that's another obvious solution.

Comment: Another complaint of mine.  Sexually mature humans have been reproducing long before the complex language to describe the process was developed.  You might as well tell them to not breath, as it's just as easy for a human to ignore the desire to breath as it is to ignore the desire to reproduce.